# Formatting E-Zine correctly for Outlook embedding

Tags: html, email, formatting, embedding

my client wants an E-Zine that can be embedded in an email along with edited and managed in an email.

A solution to this is creating a basic HTML file which is embedded into an email, upon clicking "forward" the HTML file can be edited. This is what my client wants, however I'm having trouble formatting it correctly. Has anybody else created an E-Zine and can help me understand how it's embedded or edited before it's sent out?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating complex HTML emails which look good in all possible mail clients is almost impossible. At least there are some basic rules which should make your life easier. A good article can be found [here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/code-html-email-newsletters).